# Converting a character pointer to uppercase in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a pointer:

```
char * name;
```

it contains the string `"test:case"`

And I'm calling another function with it, and trying to store it in a structure. However, I want to capitalize the entire string first, but It doesn't seem to work.

```
void func(char * name) {
    int i;
    List * l;

    l = malloc(sizeof(List));

    for(i=0; i< strlen(name); i++) {
        name[i] = toupper(name[i]);
    }

    l->name = name;
    //CALL A FUNCTION TO LATER FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY
}
```

Where `List is a struct that has a member (char *) named name.`
This however, seg faults. I can't go about using non pointers in my case. As I have to use pointers and not character arrays, I'm trying to use toupper in every value of the char pointer, however this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How are you setting `name`? It sounds like you're pointing it to a string literal. These are not modifiable, you need to make a copy of it.

Comment: Even if I don't try to uppercase it (Say remove the for loop stuff), and print out the struct value of name, it prints the correct value, not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The segfault is coming from trying to uppercase it. If you don't uppercase it, there's no problem.

Comment: A pointer does **not** contain characters. It **points to** a character array. You'll find things much easier to understand if you don't muddle the two.

Comment: Yes It's coming from me trying to uppercase it (That's what I have to do). I'm saying that doing l->name = name still gets me the right value in the struct name, regardless or not if I use strcpy.

Comment: My question is how do I uppercase it, without getting a segfault here.

Comment: Make a copy of the string, and uppercase the copy.

Comment: Does that work though. If I make a char * copy, strcpy the original into it ,and for loop through the copied string. Then store it in the struct?

Comment: I still seem to get a segfault doing that.

Comment: Supply a complete example, that can be verified... You are mentioning some code not shown where something is supposed to be freed, but no code to inspect makes it impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a segfault because the original string is presumably a literal, and it's not modifiable. You need to make a copy of it first.

```
void func(char * name) {
    List * l;

    l = malloc(sizeof(List));

    name = strdup(name); // make a copy of name
    for (char *p = name; *p; p++) {
        *p = toupper(*p);
    }

    l->name = name;
}
```

Note that when you later free `l`, you'll first need to free `l->name`.

Comment: int p = name?  Wrong type?

Comment: sorry, switched from i to p while I was typing, forgot to change the type.

Comment: How do we know src string is a literal?

Comment: @mauro Because trying to assign to it is faulting. So it's presumably a constant.

Comment: @mauro Then he would have gotten an error when he was putting `test:case` into the string in the first place.

Comment: @mauro I think he's getting the error on the `toupper` line, not on `l->name = name`.

Comment: Hmm is there anyway to get strudp to work in c11? Or will I have to stick to c99.

Comment: @TEDG `strdup` is a POSIX function, not a standard C function. It's equivalent to `dest = malloc(strlen(source)+1)` followed by `strcpy(dest, source)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only set the pointer `l->name` to `name`, this will crash the moment the original `name` is no longer there (maybe it was only on the stack?) and `l->name` is accessed. You need to `malloc()` space the size of `strlen(name)+1`, copy `name` there and set `l->name` to that address.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated the List, but not the name string itself.
You need to do:

```
l=malloc(sizeof(List));
l->name=(char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1); // You need to cater for the the final null char.
```

There are a few additional issues with your code, here is the correct one (didn't compile it, probably close to okay):

```
void func(char *name) {
  List * l;
  l = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
  l->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
  for(char *r=name, char *w=l->name; *r; ++r,++w) {
     *w = toupper(*r);
  }
  *++w='\0';
}
```

And at every iteration, this code does not evaluate again and again strlen, which would be very bad.

Comment: he didn't allocate the name itself because he wanted to point to the original string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in the code.

```
char * name
```

The variable *name* contains a pointer to a string (i.e., an array of *char*).
When you write this:

```
name[i] = toupper(name[i]);
```

you are changing the original *char* itens of the string, if it is not a pointer to a constant string. If that is the case, it is a segmentation fault.

The other mistake is here:

```
 l->name = name;
```

You are just assigning to the variable within the structure the pointer which was passed on through the variable *name* to the function. You should make a copy, like this:

```
strcpy(l->name, name);
```

This functions copies all the contents from the second argument to the first.

But that's not a good solution. If *name* contains a pointer to a constant string, it's still segmentation fault.

I'll rewrite your code:

```
void func(char * name) {
    int i;
    List * l;

    l = malloc(sizeof(List));

    char *buffer[strlen(name)]; //buffer of the contents pointed by *name* to upper case, initialized as empty string

    for(i=0; i< strlen(name); i++) {
        buffer[i] = toupper(name[i]);
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0'; //closing the string in i = strlen(name)

    strcpy(l->name, buffer);
    //CALL A FUNCTION TO LATER FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY
}
```

That way, you manipulate a copy of the original string, and than you make a copy of the buffer to the variable in the structure.

If you do this:

```
l->name = buffer;
```

you're only copying a local pointer, which will be gone with the end of the function.

I suggest you learn more about pointers, arrays and strings in C. In essence, a string is a array of char, with a '\0' in the final position. An empty string *s* has '\0' in s[0].

Edit: if you're used to languages which makes a copy of the string like this:

```
string1 = string2
```

you should always have in mind that, in C, that's pointer assignment. So, in C, that code would have to be written like this:

```
strcpy(string1, string2);
```

Hope that helps.